# Extract railroad from Orthophoto and / or LiDAR

Tags: qgis, fme-form, whitebox-gat, whitebox-tools, railroad

I would like to automate the creation of a vector line from either orthophoto or aerial LiDAR data. This line (or these lines in fact) represent both sides of a railway. We can see those pretty clearly in the DEM I extracted from the LiDAR data below. I also have the orthophoto, taken at the same time. However, the shadow may be problematic in the long run since I do have a pretty long distance to cover. I do have access to FME, CloudCompare, PDAL / GDAL, QGIS, WhiteBox Tools, ArcGIS Pro. I dabble with these things so far without being able to defining a clear pipeline I could use. Let me know if you have any idea.

[image: Hillshade sample]

[image: Orthophoto sample]

Comment: Aren't these data available at Open Street Map?

Comment: @GBG Think they wanting higher accuracy than OSM data?

Comment: Do you have a sample to try and make something work?

Comment: I've been somewhat successful in detecting [ditches](https://minkarta.lantmateriet.se/plats/3006/v1.0/?e=647775&n=6693032&z=13&mapprofile=terrangskuggning&background=3&boundaries=false) in a DEM using a hillshade as input to [scikit Image Straight line Hough transform](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html)